# Print a space in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im echoing some data from a database using PHP. However the data is too close together and needs a space in between each one.

```
while($book = mysql_fetch_array($books)) {
    echo '<div>'
                .$book['title'] 
                .$book['author'] 
                .$book['genre'] 
                .$book['price'] 
                .$book['availability']        
        .'</div>';
}
```

Is their a way to print a break maybe after each one to give a space.

Cheers

Comment: Where are you outputting this, browser? If so entities would do or a plain whitespace. The plain whitespace route will only work for one space though. The entities won't work command line, text file, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print it as html entity `&nbsp;`:

```
echo '<div>'
        .$book['title'] . '&nbsp;'
        .$book['author'] . '&nbsp;'
        .$book['genre'] . '&nbsp;'
        .$book['price'] . '&nbsp;'
        .$book['availability']
   . '</div>';
```

Comment: Cheers! Worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

yes, and the answer is shown below

```
    while($book = mysql_fetch_array($books)) {
        echo '<div>'
            .$book['title']." "
                .$book['author']." "
                .$book['genre']." "
                .$book['price']." " 
                .$book['availability']." " 

        .'</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [curly syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in the [double quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) strings:

```
echo "<div>{$book['title']} {$book['author']} {$book['genre']} {$book['price']} {$book['availability']}</div>";
```

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

Answer (score 0):

To add my five cents )

```
while($book = mysql_fetch_array($books)) {
    echo "<div>{$book['title']} 
                {$book['author']}
                {$book['genre']} 
                {$book['price']} 
                {$book['availability']}</div>";
}
```